# Formatting not being copied over when using PasteSpecial

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Excel sheet which has many conditional formatting rules. When I do a PasteSpecial to another sheet all the formatting disappears. 
Why is that? 
I need to keep all the rules in unfortunately.

I have tried with xlPasteFormats, xlPasteAll etc but then Excel freezes and hangs.

```
Sheets("Data").Activate
Range("A1:H12").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Output").Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers and looking at my questions.

I ended up using

Paste:=xlPasteValues

Paste:=xlPasteFormats

This copied the formatting over.

The reason everything was so slow was because one of the sheets had lots of duplicate Conditional Formatting rules.
I deleted and recreated the sheet with only two Conditional Formatting rules and it was lightning quick.

Answer (score 3):

You could just do a regular copy/paste

or the argument in PasteSpecial:

```
Paste:=xlPasteAllMergingConditionalFormats
```

And if you search SO you'll find some information as to why you should be avoiding the use of `Select` and `Activate`.  Using a regular copy/paste operation, your macro could be rewritten as a one-liner:

```
Sheets("Data").Range("A1:H12").Copy Sheets("Output").Range("A1")
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for this. I tried the Paste Option you mentioned but Excel just hangs. I think its because there are many conditional formatting rules on that specific sheet. I can't remove these rules unfortunately.

Comment: @RShome How long did you let it sit there?  What happens if you disable calculations and events? Are you running into any of the format limits?

Comment: Hi @Ron Rosenfeld, this workbook doesn't actually have any calculations or events. When I use xlPasteNumberAndValuesFormats it works fine, pasting the sheet into a new workbook loses all formatting BUT it runs in ten seconds. With formatting it hangs for >10 mins and I just cancel it. What would the format limits be?

Comment: @RShome Do in internet search for something like `Excel Specifications and Limits` and you can see there.  I'm afraid that without being able to reproduce your problem, I will not be able to help further.  I think that can only be done if you can upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) that reproduces the problem to some sharing site and post a link here.